# How to play background audio Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841209.aspx) article about "How to play audio in the background (XAML)" and works,i played my mp3 file well,but if i try to out from app the music just stop,i thought "background audio" was to play even if the app was not focus on screen!

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <MediaElement x:Name="musicPlayer" 
      Source="Assets/VIGEVANO.mp3"
      AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia"
      CurrentStateChanged="MusicPlayer_CurrentStateChanged" />

</Grid>
```

CS

```
SystemMediaTransportControls systemControls;
public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        // Hook up app to system transport controls.
        systemControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
        systemControls.ButtonPressed += SystemControls_ButtonPressed;

        // Register to handle the following system transpot control buttons.
        systemControls.IsPlayEnabled = true;
        systemControls.IsPauseEnabled = true;

    }

private void SystemControls_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Button)
        {
            case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Play:
                PlayMedia();
                break;
            case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause:
                PauseMedia();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    async void PlayMedia()
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            musicPlayer.Play();
        });
    }

    async void PauseMedia()
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            musicPlayer.Pause();
        });
    }
```

[image: Manifest File]

What i miss?

Comment: DID you register even the events in your code as shown in the example since last time I worked with that example it was working great

Comment: yes, but i dont know why is not working.. did you have other link about this?

Comment: Well usually it does ask if you want to allow your application to run in background at the start and you should accept it. Try uninstall and reinstall the generated solution in your testing device

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/basic-media-playback-003619be Download and run this sample and see if its working or not

Comment: @Jerin if go to my Desktop the audio stop to play!

Comment: Are you running the app in Windows phone emulator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78971/discussion-between-jerin-and-nathiel-paulino).

Answer (score 0):

Summary answer reached
Since Background Streaming was the main requirement so the solution reached was
Yes Check out this [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Audio-Streamer-e85b8deb) and let me know if it works for you.
Your background task first tutorial works for local mp3 files but streaming audio is a different scenario in itself
Also for streaming we used to use [PhoneSM](http://phonesm.codeplex.com)